# Distance (20cm or 30cm) as categorical or continuous variable?

Tags: categorical-data, linear-model, continuous-data

I am doing a linear model using R, looking at the heating efficiency of three infrared lamps. The explanatory variable is the **time taken to heat the core temperature of an animal model to 25C**. The response variables are **lamp types** and the **distance between the lamp and the animal model.**

I only tested the *distance at 20cm or 30cm* and see whether distance matters for the heating efficiency. I wonder whether I should treat the **Distance** variable as **categorical** (20cm and 30cm) or as a **continuous variable** in the linear model?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean that you are using `distance` and `lamp type` to predict the `time taken to heat the core temperature`?

Comment: I am looking at whether different lamp types and different distances affect the time taken to heat the core temperature